# How can I securely use client_id and api key in gmail extension for chrome?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-oauth, gmail-api

Right now I have hard-coded all my keys in the background page. Do I need to secure access_token that is generated after authorization is successful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using Google OAuth, they're pretty secured unless you explicitly want to expose them. Also, just [place your client_id in your manifest](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_identity) like every chrome extension developer does.

Comment: After retrieving token using chrome.identity.getAuthToken, how can i use this token to call gmail apis? When i go to [gmail api site for javascript](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/js), i see loading a client library script and using gapi keyword to make request to apis.